# How to route none http request in pound.cfg

Tags: debian, redirection, tcp, hypervisor

I'm trying to route all request that point on the port 3050 to another host, here is what i usually write in the /etc/pound/pound.cfg:

```
ListenHTTP
       Address 10.165.30.58
       Port    3050
    Service
        BackEnd
            Address 10.10.101.10
            Port    3050
        End
    End
End
```

But the request is not an HTTP request but a simple TCP request, what shall i do ?

Please note that my example do not works

Comment: I replaced *root* with *route* in your question. I hope that was correct.